# Angular 2 : Open custom modal popup and lock the tab closing when the user closes a browser tab

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I am facing something really strange. In an Angular 2 web application, I need, when the user closes a browser tab or the browser itself, to show a custom modal popup that will propose the user to stay or to leave (and sending some action to my API by the way). In fact, I need to lock the tab closing before the user make a choice.

Here is the code below allowing to detect the tab closing, then to open the modal popup but it doesn’t prevent the tab from closing.

Anybody encountered the same problem? Thank you in advance for your help.

From app.component.ts

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
private beforeUnloadHander(event) {
     this.translate.get('WINDOW.title').subscribe(
        value => {
            this.modalTitle = value
        });
     this.componentChild = {
        component: ModalCloseWindowComponent,
        inputs: {}
     };
};
```

From app.component.html :

```
  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <modal [title]="modalTitle" [componentChild]="componentChild" (onClose)="close(event)"></modal>
</main>
```

The modal popup part is made of 2 components, a generic one for all modals popups and a custom for the CloseWindow one.

From modal.component.ts (the generic part):

```
  import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})

export class ModalComponent {

    @ViewChild('theBody', { read: ViewContainerRef })  public theBody;
    private currentComponent: ComponentRef<any>;
    private visible = false;
    private visibleAnimate = false;
    @Output() public onClose = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() public title: string;
    // todo trouver comment géré la popup autrement pour enlever les any
    @Input() set componentChild(data: { component: any, inputs: Object[] }) {
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }
        // Injecte les inputs dont l'enfant a besion
        let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => { return { provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName] }; });
        let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

        // Crée l'injecteur à partir des données que l'on veut transmettre
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.theBody.parentInjector);

        // on crée la factory du component
        let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);

        // on crée le component qui utilise l'injecteur et la factory
        this.currentComponent = factory.create(injector);

        // on insert le component dans le dom container
        this.theBody.insert(this.currentComponent.hostView);

        // Overture de la fenêtre
        this.show();

        // on souscrit des events de sortie
        // this.currentComponent = component;
        this.currentComponent.instance.onClose.subscribe(dataOnClose => {
            this.hide();
            this.onClose.emit(dataOnClose);
        });
        this.currentComponent.instance.close.subscribe(dataClose => this.hide());
    }

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    public show(): void {
        // window.parent.event.preventDefault();
        // window.parent.event.stopPropagation();
        // window.onbeforeunload = null;
        // window.parent.event.cancelBubble = true;
        //// window.parent.event.returnValue = false;
        // window.parent.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        this.visible = true;
        this.visibleAnimate = true;
    }

    public hide(): void {
        this.visibleAnimate = false;
        if (this.currentComponent) {
            this.currentComponent.destroy();
        }
        this.currentComponent = null;
        this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

From modal.component.html (the generic part):

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
     [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none'}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div #theBody></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"
     [ngStyle]="{'display': visible ? 'block' : 'none'}"></div>
```

From modalCloseWindow.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit, ElementRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal-close-window',
    templateUrl: './modalCloseWindow.component.html'
})

export class ModalCloseWindowComponent {

    @Output() public onClose = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() public close = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService,
        public fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    public hide(): void {
        this.close.emit(false);
    }

    public quitter(): void {
        this.onClose.emit(true);
    }
}
```

From modalCloseWindow.component.html ;

```
<form class="form cf">
    <div class="form-item">
        <p>{{ 'WINDOW.stopEnregistrement' | translate }} </p>
        <p>{{ 'WINDOW.infoStopEnregistrement' | translate }} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions cf">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" (click)="hide()">{{ 'WINDOW.rester' | translate }} </button> &nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="quitter()">{{ 'WINDOW.quitter' | translate }} </button>
    </div>
</form>
```